# How to fetch Upstream build number in Jenkins 2.103

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I tried installed Parameterized Build Plugin, but it doesn't shown in Jenkins Configure Page.

We are executing a Pipeline project with the script.
I am using Jenkins ver. 2.103.

I have two projects **A** and **B**.
**A** is parent project.
**B** is child project.

**B** needs **A** Last successful build number.

I have tried a couple of solutions on StackOverflow and other forums but no luck.

Answer (score -1):

because I am using Jenkins Pipeline no plugins works for me .
I used Shell script to update latest succesful build number to a file and use the same in other job.

Share file data between jobs.